# Выделение вводного слова "возможно"

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

"Сейчас она не даёт никаких бонусов, но если продолжите развиваться, то(,) возможно(,) и будет"

С одной стороны, здесь это вводное слово, но с другой стороны, если его выкинуть, получится неразбериха. "То и будет". Если бы не было "и", я бы не сомневался, но здесь не уверен.

Answer (score 2):

Никаких сомнений, это вводное слово. Если его изъять, получится разговорная неполная конструкция:

"*Сейчас она не даёт никаких бонусов, но если продолжите развиваться, то и будет (давать)"*. Всё нормально и понятно.

Comment: Понимаю, что вводное, что его нужно обособить, но мне, как и автору вопроса, странно видеть И в таком предложении (после изъятия вводного).

Comment: Но это же разговорная конструкция, там часто И используют как усилительную частицу, на пунктуацию это никак не влияет: "Тогда-то мы и пришли". "И"  здесь как бы входит в оборот: то и, тогда-то и, вот и.